# Foundation 2010 workflow not starting automatically(not a system account)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow

Does anyone have any suggestions how to fix a workflow would not be starting automatically?

This is NOT a system account (just a regular user with contribute permissions to list). This is a standalone install with services running under default Network service.

I even created a new "workflow user", and published Workflow as it to be sure. If I tell workflow to run manually, it works fine.

Comment: How is the workflow being started by list change, email, approval ect.?

Comment: Workflow is set to start on item creation. I tested this tons yesterday, and it just "started working". Tested it with multiple accounts and all worked fine. Today it's not working again. No idea why.

Comment: Again It's strange. Regular user adds new item to list, workflow doesn't start at all. I create a "dummy" item, and it worked fine.

Comment: Does the workflow say it has completed, or are you getting an error?  Make sure your list data matches the column type or the workflow will not work.  If someone puts a letter in a number field, for example it will break.

Comment: NO workflow errors at all. Either the workflow doesn't start at all or it completes fine.

Comment: well if it runs on some and no the other I would say it has to be either a permissions thing, or something to do with their user profile.  If the workflow was the problem, it would not work at all. Check the user permissions for those who are having the problem.  Check the site level as well as the list level.

Comment: permissions are fine or user wouldn't be able to create item at all. I am thinking something must have got corrupted somewhere and think I'll try deleting and recreating workflow from scratch

Comment: Looks like the first item created each day "skips" starting the workflow and subsequent workflows after that run. I will try recreating it from scratch

Comment: I know it sounds simple, but make sure you workflow is set to start when an item is created :0  I have missed that before without thinking.

Comment: @Chris I have the exact same problem. Workflows do not start on the first item, but on the following ones. Did you find a solution to this?